# How to change CSS attributes from dynamically loaded external HTML files with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery. So far, I could google all of my problems but with the following issue I need help.

To keep the `index.html` small to read I inject certain div containers having given IDs with external stored HTML files using the `jQuery load` function (I cannot do it with a server side language like PHP as the CMS I am using does not allow to use `<?php><?>` tags. So I am stuck with client side solutions.).

This works fine :-). However, I need to change some CSS attributes after loading. However, the content dynamically loaded with jQuery cannot be touched with jQuery.

Here is a demo code of what I try to achieve:

My `index.html` I am calling:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Injection Test</title>
    <style>
        .textformat {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#includeHere").load("tobeincluded.html");

            $(".textformat").css("text-align", "center");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="includeHere"></div>
<div class="textformat">Bye</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `tobeincluded.html` I am injecting:

```
<div class="textformat">Hi</div>
```

I would expect that "Hi" is centered, too. But only "Bye" is centered as it is available in the DOM right from the beginning.

How do I make "Hi" centered?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to wait until [load has completed](https://api.jquery.com/load/), so apply the css in the callback of the `.load()` method

```
$("#includeHere").load("tobeincluded.html", function() {
  $(".textformat").css("text-align", "center");
});
```

Comment: That's it!!! JS Callbacks have been new to me. Learnt something new today :-)

Comment: js is fundamentally asynchronous. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous